# Handling bad records in airflow dag

Tags: etl, airflow

I need an airflow dag to do something like this

download_file >> parse_file >> enrich_file

But if say while parsing i find "bad" records, i need to store it in a db, have the user correct it and then automatically trigger a dag to proceeed to enrich_file for those corrected records. for the "good" records i want the original instance of the dag to complete. Is this possible to do this kind of forking in airflow. is this even the correct tool for this use case or should i stick to messaging and queues ?

Comment: How will you know when the user has corrected "bad records"?

Comment: So, we would have a UI on the bad records. Have the user correct them. validate in the UI program and then trigger a airflow workflow once validated.

Comment: I think it should be like  - the file would be received > it is parsed using some logic in python > it will create 2 files(one with good records and one with bad records) > the good records file would be processed in airflow > the bad records file loaded to a db and UI would be built on that and user will correct it > the corrected file will again be placed in the directory from first step.

Comment: One the bad file is placed in the directory, would i trigger the dag from code and there would be another instance of the dag ?

Comment: There can be 2 options: After bad records file is corrected, instantiate the dag run again and it will be picked up. OR If you are sure that you would not get another file till you process this one completely then  - You can create 2 branches in the same DAG, one for good records and one for bad records. After correcting the bad records, keep the bad records file in another directory and have bad records branch to sense that particular directory. As soon as the file is placed, the branch would be triggered.

Comment: I liked the second option. in my dag, i will have multiple tasks which will generate good/bad records. Some of them as files, some of them in sql staging tables. For each task if i branch it and let the good go thru, and trigger the corrected "bad" (based on some user action), and let it go. I didnt know you could trigger a part of the dag. I will try it out. Thanks !

Comment: I read about sensors. One issue is i can only trigger the bad branch once. So when there is are multiple bad records. and the user takes longer time to fix certain records, i have to wait to have all records fixed and then trigger the branch. I rather have fixed records go thru the pipeline immediately. So i would have to go with option #1. i.e instantiate the dag run again for each fixed record.